# How do I get placemark icons to load over ssl?

Tags: ssl, https, kml, google-earth-plugin

I'm working on a web application that uses the google earth plugin. Recently, a new requirement to have non-public users logon was added, which meant that some users were now using the site over https. Among the things that broke in testing were the custom placemark icons (They were working using http).

The icons are hosted on the same server which servers the page.

Here are the urls for each of the protocols.

```
 http - http://localhost/Images/yellow.png
 https - https://localhost/Images/yellow.png
```

I can follow that link and the image will appear as you would expect.

The images hrefs are declared as icon styles in dynamically generated kml.

I want to avoid loading the images over http because I think that will cause internet explorer to present the user with a mixed content warning.

How do I get the images to load properly while using https?

Comment: are you loading the api over SSL? i.e. `https://www.google.com/jsapi/` not `http://www.google.com/jsapi/`

Comment: Thanks for the interest, Fraser. I am loading the api over SSL.

Comment: OK, can you see the outgoing request for the images (using fiddler or similar) - from the plug-in? I am interested to see what request is made for the image files. Also are you using a self-signed certificate or one signed by a certificate authority for the SSL?

Comment: Hi Fraser. I tried using fiddler but I'm a novice with it so I couldn't get anything useful. I did look at the network activity in Chrome's developer tools. After I removed other references to the same images (a legend on the same page as the map is on), Chrome didn't report that the images were being fetched, which likely means that it couldn't see what google Earth was doing.

Edit: To answer the latter question, it's a self signed cert on both my dev machine and our test environment. I'm going to get our production admin to test in on production and see if the legit cert helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wrestling with this myself -- the short answer is that this won't work. If the content is served off of an HTTPS site that generates any kind of error/prompt (authentication, invalid certificate, etc.) the plugin will simply not load the content.

Interestingly, the desktop client works fine and prompts the user for credentials if necessary. However, neither client will allow content to be served off of site with an untrusted certificate.

The only workaround that I have found is:

- Use a trusted HTTPS certificate on the server hosting the content (either trust the certificate on the client systems or just use a real certificate.)
- Do not use HTTPS basic auth as that will always generate 401/Challenge responses which the web browser client will simply ignore
- If authentication is a requirement, use NTLM authentication and common (e.g., domain) logins. If you load the plugin in Interent Explorer (or in a .NET WebBrowserControl) the authentication will be handled properly and the images will show up.

I was at a Google Earth administrator's training last week and the trainer confirmed this "bug". It is supposed to be fixed in the next version of the plugin (it may actually be fixed already -- what version of the plugin are you using?)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked Programs and Features, and it says that Google Earth Plug-in has product version 6.2.2.6613

Comment: Yeah - the google guy I was talking with said the fix should be out in 7 if I remember right. Might want to try the KML/Google Earth google groups too. Also please remember to accept answers you find helpful.