# Can't get Google Earth plugin to load ground overlays requiring a cert?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-earth-plugin

Using plugin version 6.2.2.x I cannot seem to load ground overlays that require a certificate to access. The code snippet like the following causes the plugin to request a cert from the user but it seems to ignore it as the plugin does not get the overlay and displays the missing overlay red X.

```
   this.groundOverlay = this.earth.createGroundOverlay('');
   this.overlayImg = this.earth.createIcon('');
   this.viewBb = this.earth.getView().getViewportGlobeBounds();

   this.overlayImg.setHref('https://host:port/wms?...');
   this.groundOverlay.setIcon(this.overlayImg);
   this.groundOverlay.setLatLonBox(this.viewBb);
   this.earth.getFeatures().appendChild(this.groundOverlay);
```

Does anyone know whether this should/should not work? I've read about the cert issues with the GE thick client but nothing about the plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get placemark icons to load over ssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963939/how-do-i-get-placemark-icons-to-load-over-ssl)

Comment: This is the same issue as the above question. Both are about loading resources over ssl to the google earth plugin which is the general problem. The element type is irrelevant.